# Counting instances of letter sequences

Tags: java, arraylist, stream, hashmap

The purpose of this code is to count the instances of letters that occur in sequence, using HashMaps, and Streams.

I've run into the problem of my System.out.print(results) is printing [is=3, imple=2, it=1] to the console, but my junit is saying "expected <[is=3 imple =2 it=1]> but was <[]>.

The code prints out [is=3, imple=2, it=1] but it doesn't seem to actually be updating this out into memory. Any tips or advice on what I should do? 
Thank you so much!

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class WordCount {

protected Map<String, Integer> counts;
static Scanner in= new Scanner(System.in);

public WordCount(){

    counts = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

}
public Map getCounts(){

    return counts;
}

public int parse(Scanner in, Pattern pattern){
        int counter=0;
        while   (in.hasNext())  {
        //  get the next    token
        String  token   =   in.next();
        //  match   the pattern within  the token
        Matcher matcher =   pattern.matcher(token);
        //  process each    match   found   in  token   (could  be  more    than    one)
        while   (matcher.find())    {
                        //  get the String  that    matched the pattern
            String  s   =   matcher.group().trim();
                        //  now do  something   with    s

            counter=counts.containsKey(s) ? counts.get(s):0;
            counts.put(s,counter+1);
            }

        }


        return counter;
}


public void report(PrintStream printstream){
    List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> results = new ArrayList<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>();
    for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry: counts.entrySet()){
        results.add(entry);
        Collections.sort(results,Collections.reverseOrder(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()));
        results.toString();

    }



    System.out.println(results); // The main problem is this outputs [is=3, 
imple=2, it=1] but the junit doesn't pass.


}


}

//Test Cases 


import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import junit.framework.TestCase;

public class TestWordCount extends TestCase {
public void test_WordCount_parse() {
    WordCount wc = new WordCount();
    Scanner in = new Scanner("this is a simple test, but it is not simple to pass");
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[i][a-z]+");
    wc.parse(in, pattern);

    assertEquals((Integer)3, wc.getCounts().get("is"));
    assertEquals((Integer)2, wc.getCounts().get("imple"));
    assertEquals((Integer)1, wc.getCounts().get("it"));

}

    public void test_WordCount_report() {
    WordCount wc = new WordCount();
    Scanner in = new Scanner("this is a simple test, but it is not simple to pass");
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[i][a-z]+");
    wc.parse(in, pattern);

    ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    wc.report(new PrintStream(output));
    String out = output.toString();
    String ls = System.lineSeparator();

    assertEquals("is=3_imple=2_it=1_".replace("_", ls), out);
   }
```

Comment: Make your report method to return the result explicitly.

Comment: So changing the "System.out.println(results)" to "return(results); seems to result in the same output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
`public void report(PrintStream printstream)`
```

In this method you do not print anything to `printstream`. Try adding

```
printstream.print(results);
```

to this method.

Note that, although `System.out` is a `PrintStream` itself, it's a different stream that is bound to the console.

Comment: Thank you, that gets me an actual output! I now have the output <[[is=3,imple=2,it=1]]> but that's probably due to something fundamental in my report method. I appreciate your help!